# What are the slashes with letters (/b, /m, /e, /p, ...) used for?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

What are the slashes with letters for – as seen in `set /p` or `for /f`  etc?

Comment: Some command even take more than one letter, e.g. `Start /max CMD.EXE`. There's also a `/min` option to `Start`, so /m` would be quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are "command line switches", and you use them to give a command more information about what you want it to do.

For example, the `dir` command lists the files in the working directory, one file per line.  If you say `dir /w` then it lists them in "wide" format, with several files per line.  `/w` is a "command line switch".

To find out information about a particular switch, you need to read the documentation for the command it relates to.  For `dir`, you can type `dir /?` - the `/?` switch tells the command to give you help about how it works, including the switches that it accepts.

The two commands you mention, `set` and `for`, also accept the `/?` switch.

Comment: nearly every command has a "help switch", normally  `/?` . Try for example `set /?` or `for /?`

Answer (score 1):

The slashes are parameters

If you want to know what parameter for, add "/?" in your command

For example :

```
copy /? --> this will show you all about copy command
```

Comment: Yeah, but what i wanted to know was what the letters after the slashes mean.

Comment: @Swillfreat: As the other answer states, the meaning of the letters is specific to each program/command. Use program_name /? or /h or -?  or -h or --help etc.